# Did Red Hat end the developer subscription program?

Tags: rhel, redhat-satellite

My Red Hat developer subscription ended yesterday.  I'd like to know if Red Hat discontinued the program, because after following every single instruction on their site and contacting customer service (via email) there is no solution to help developers renew the subscription. Here is what I have attempted so far:

I signed in to the [developer portal](https://developers.redhat.com/) but I was not asked to agree to the Terms and conditions, which should happen when your subscription expires. Since that didn't happen I invoked the download of the RHEL ISO, but again I was not asked to agree to the Terms & Conditions.

My only option left to log out and log back in, and that didn't help either, So I contacted customer service with the problem. This is is the second day, and they have not replied yet.

Their Support link redirects me to [Stack Overflow](https://developers.redhat.com/help/#!q=).

Comment: My experience was that the free developer subscription expired after a year and there was no discernable way to renew for free. You might ask if it's legit to create a new ID.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick yes you can renew the developer subscription for free. Because this is my second time. I did renew this very same subscription a year ago. What i don't understand is why do people in this forum find the need to downvote this question. Sometimes if you don't have an answer to a valid question, it is best to keep your downvoting clicks to yourselves. Because this right here is just appalling outright disgusting

Comment: Thanks. My non-renewal experience is from a couple months ago. I was surprised, and thought that maybe they curtailed the program. (I didn't downvote you).

Comment: As far as I’m aware the program is still very much alive! What does the subscription manager, running on your RHEL system, say about your developer subscriptions?

Comment: Hi! Please don't misuse quote formatting for emphasis or highlighting.

Comment: @StephenKitt when i run `Auto-attach` i get the message saying `No service level will cover all installed products. Please manually subscribe using multiple service levels vial "All Available Subscriptions" tab or purchase additional subscriptions.`  But when i go to all available subscriptions and click on update it doesn't bring up any active subscription

Comment: Hmm, now the customer portal lets me download images. It didn't a few months ago. Maybe I just had to wait a bit after agreeing to the terms and conditions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a RedHat issue it has nothing to do with Linux in itself.

Comment: @Kiwy Are you trying to score some points or what. Are you trying to say that hundreds of developers who are having this problem should be denied a proper solution to a situation because YOU feel that this is not a Linux problem?

Comment: Christian, the reason this is off topic is because it isn't a technical problem but an issue with RH's subscription model. That's something that only RH can help you with. This site only deals with technical issues about *nix-like operating systems. So a question about the subscription model used by a specific company is not on topic here.

Comment: @christianx I think Terdon answers you properly. I'm not trying to do anything against you. This is not my nature, just to keep this site with on topic question (linux/unix, programming on linux, tools, and other technical issue) We can't say anything for RedHat as we are not there support team. I'm glad however that you posted you answer and I hope to see you on SE Unix & Linux in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Red Hat finally got back to me 3 days after opening a support case regarding the developer subscription. 
According to them (Red Hat) the developer’s subscription need to completely expire before the one can be prompted to accept new terms and conditions for their new license. 
This argument makes no sense because if your subscription ends today for example, you are automatically disconnected from all `repositories` and `redhat` servers. My conclusion on this topic is that developers with soon to expire licenses have to account for at least a day or two without access to Red Hat resources until their new licenses kicks in. I assume you know that your new license has kicked in when you are prompted to accept the new terms and conditions.